# Ethereum blockchain analysis

Tags: blockchain

My purpose is to analyze some Ethereum transactions. Which is the best way to download the full blockchain on my machine, and which libraries do you recommend for interacting with it using Python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a reddit post describing how to download the ethereum blockchain, https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5viint/how_to_download_and_install_ethereum_wallet_and/

Comment: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is a little complicated and has some extra steps because things have changed since then. If you are willing to wait while the sync is complete, just download and install the Ethereum wallet from git and choose the main network during install.

Try this tutorial https://medium.com/@attores/step-by-step-guide-getting-started-with-ethereum-mist-wallet-772a3cc99af4

For Python, try https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guide on how to export Ethereum data to csv https://medium.com/@medvedev1088/exporting-and-analyzing-ethereum-blockchain-f5353414a94e

It uses https://github.com/medvedev1088/ethereum-etl which outputs the data into `blocks.csv`, `transactions.csv`, `erc20_transfers.csv`.

`blocks.csv`

```
Column                  | Type               |
------------------------|---------------------
block_number            | bigint             |
block_hash              | hex_string         |
block_parent_hash       | hex_string         |
block_nonce             | hex_string         |
block_sha3_uncles       | hex_string         |
block_logs_bloom        | hex_string         |
block_transactions_root | hex_string         |
block_state_root        | hex_string         |
block_miner             | hex_string         |
block_difficulty        | bigint             |
block_total_difficulty  | bigint             |
block_size              | bigint             |
block_extra_data        | hex_string         |
block_gas_limit         | bigint             |
block_gas_used          | bigint             |
block_timestamp         | bigint             |
block_transaction_count | bigint             |
```

`transactions.csv`

```
Column              |    Type     |
--------------------|--------------
tx_hash             | hex_string  |
tx_nonce            | bigint      |
tx_block_hash       | hex_string  |
tx_block_number     | bigint      |
tx_index            | bigint      |
tx_from             | hex_string  |
tx_to               | hex_string  |
tx_value            | bigint      |
tx_gas              | bigint      |
tx_gas_price        | bigint      |
tx_input            | hex_string  |
```

`erc20_transfers.csv`

```
Column              |    Type     |
--------------------|--------------
erc20_token         | hex_string  |
erc20_from          | hex_string  |
erc20_to            | hex_string  |
erc20_value         | bigint      |
erc20_tx_hash       | hex_string  |
erc20_block_number  | bigint      |
```